# My IN clause leads to a full scan of an index in T-SQL. What can I do?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, indexing

I have a sql query with 50 parameters, such as this one.

```
DECLARE
  @p0 int, @p1 int, @p2 int, (text omitted), @p49 int

SELECT
  @p0=111227, @p1=146599, @p2=98917, (text omitted), @p49=125319

--
SELECT
  [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[Amount],
  [t0].[OrderID], [t0].[InvoiceNumber]
FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[CustomerID]) IN
  (@p0, @p1, @p2, (text omitted), @p49)
```

The estimated execution plan shows that the database will collect these parameters, order them, and then *read the index Orders.CustomerID* **from the smallest parameter to the largest**, then do a bookmark lookup for the rest of the record.

The problem is that there the smallest and largest parameter could be quite far apart and this will lead to reading possibly the entire index.

Since this is being done in a loop from the client side (50 params sent each time, for **1000 iterations**), this is a bad situation.  How can I formulate the query/client side code to get my data without repetitive index scanning while keeping the number of round trips down?

---

I thought about ordering the 50k parameters such that smaller readings of the index would occur.  There is a wierd mitigating circumstance that prevents this - I can't use this solution.  To model this circumstance, just assume that I only have 50 id's available at any time and can't control their relative position in the global list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Insert the parameters into a temporary table, then join it with your table:

```
DECLARE @params AS TABLE(param INT);

INSERT
INTO    @params
VALUES  (@p1)
...
INSERT
INTO    @params
VALUES  (@p49)

SELECT
  [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[Amount],
  [t0].[OrderID], [t0].[InvoiceNumber]
FROM @params, [dbo].[Orders] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[CustomerID]) = @params.param
```

This will most probably use `NESTED LOOPS` with a `INDEX SEEK` over `CustomerID` on each loop.

Comment: Good advice and provides the expected plan.  Small syntax fix - can't do = that way, use IN or JOIN

Answer (score 1):

An index range scan is pretty fast.  There's usually a lot less data in the index than in the table and there's a much better chance that the index is already in memory.

I can't blame you for wanting to save round trips to the server by putting each of the IDs your looking for in a bundle.  If the index RANGE scan really worries you, you can create a parameterized server side cursor (e.g., in TSQL) that takes the CustomerID as a parameter.  Stop as soon as you find a match.  That query should definitely use an index unique scan instead of a range scan.

Comment: An index scan is still to be avoided - it's much worse than a seek if the index is at all large. You still end up effectively with one query per customer, which isn't good design - see @quassnoi's answer.

Comment: @Arnshea, yes the index range scan is pretty fast.  This same plan is used against 10 other tables and they aren't a problem.  It turns out that the plan in this query isn't actually the problem - it's strictly the volume of data.

Answer (score 1):

To build on Quassnoi's answer, if you were working with SQL 2008, you could save yourself some time by inserting all 50 items with one statement. SQL 2008 has a new feature for multiple valued inserts.
e.g.

```
INSERT INTO @Customers (CustID)
VALUES (@p0),
       (@p1),
       <snip>
       (@p49)
```

Now @Customers table is populated and ready to `INNER JOIN` on, or your `IN` clause.